# I'm Trying to sort a user's post by location and displaying the distance using PFGeopoint and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I'm attempting to sort user's post by distance and hide any that would be over a certain set of miles. I'm also trying to sort from nearest to farthest all in my UITableview:

```
class FindAParty:UITableViewController{

    //var partyData:NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()
    var partyData = [PFObject]()
    //var user:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    override init(style: UITableViewStyle){
        super.init(style: style)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        //fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")

    }


    @IBAction func loadData(){

        PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocation { (geopoint, error) in

            print(geopoint)
            if let geopoint = geopoint {
                PFUser.current()?.remove(forKey: "Location")

                print ("True")
            PFUser.current()? ["Location"] = geopoint
                PFUser.current()?.saveInBackground()


             }

        }




        print ("Load Data went through")
        partyData.removeAll()
        print ("Remove ALL Objeccts")
        let findPartyData = PFQuery(className: "Party")

        print("PFQuery...")
        findPartyData.findObjectsInBackground {
            (objects:[PFObject]?, error:Error?)->Void in

            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
            } else{
                if let objects = objects {
                    self.partyData = objects.reversed()
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.loadData()
        print("View Did Appear")
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("ViewDidLoad")
        //self.loadData()
        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // #pragma mark - Table view data source
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return partyData.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! FindAPartyCell

       let party = self.partyData[indexPath.row]





        cell.typeOfPartyLabel.alpha = 0
        cell.timeOfPartyLabel.alpha = 0
        cell.usernameLabel.alpha = 0
        cell.alcoholTFLabel.alpha = 0

        cell.typeOfPartyLabel.text = party.object(forKey: "partyTitle") as? String
        cell.timeOfPartyLabel.text = party.object(forKey: "partyTime") as? String
        cell.usernameLabel.text = party.object(forKey: "Usernames") as? String
        cell.alcoholTFLabel.text = party.object(forKey: "ATF") as? String

       // var dataFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        //dataFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
        //cell.timestampLabel.text = dataFormatter.stringFromDate(sweet.createdAt)

       /* let findUser:PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
        findUser.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: party.object(forKey: "Username")!)


        findUser.findObjectsInBackground {
            (objects:[PFObject]?, error: Error?) -> Void in // Changes NSError to Error
            if error == nil{

                let user:PFUser = (objects)!.last as! PFUser
                cell.usernameLabel.text = user.username

               */ UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                    cell.typeOfPartyLabel.alpha = 1
                    cell.timeOfPartyLabel.alpha = 1
                    cell.usernameLabel.alpha = 1
                    cell.alcoholTFLabel.alpha = 1
                })
            //}
        //}


        return cell
    }


}
```

I would also like to show the distance if possible. 
Thank You for any advice

Answer (score 0):

You could use geo-queries, provided by Parse.

`whereKey:nearGeoPoint`

Returns an array of objects ordered by distance (nearest to farthest)

`whereKey:nearGeoPoint:withinMiles`/ `whereKey:nearGeoPoint:withinKilometers`

Limit the results using distance (m/km)

1. Query Users by "Location" (you should consider using lowercase for attributes)

   `let query = PFUser.query()!
   query.whereKey("Location", nearGeoPoint: geopoint)`
2. Get their posts...(Separate Posts table ? Uses Relationships?)